# Unable to enter superuser using su

Tags: command-line, permissions, root, su

Whenever I try to run

```
su
Password:
```

Then it shows error

```
setgid: Operation not permitted
```

This problem arose after I changed permissions using `chown`

Output of `ls -lsa /bin/su` is:

```
40 -rwxrwxr-x 1 jheel root 40128 May 17 2017 /bin/su
```

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -lsa /bin/su`

Comment: its 40 -rwxrwxr-x 1 jheel root 40128 May 17  2017 /bin/su

Comment: *"This problem arose after I changed permissions using `chown`"* What `chown` command did you run, exactly? If you ran `chown` on just `/bin/su`, then you will be able to fix this easily. If you ran it on many files, then the process of fixing it may be more involved, especially if you used `chown -R` on a directory. The issue is that you may have `chown`ed other programs needed to undo the `chown`. Can you **[edit]** this with the exact `chown` command/commands you used? The good news is that it's usually easier to undo `chown`ing than `chmod`ing, since ownership varies less than permissions.

Comment: _"This problem arose after I changed permissions using `chown`"_ - `chown` doesn't change permissions, it changes ownership. `chmod` changes permissions.

Comment: @marcelm, though doing a `chown` does drop the setuid bit, which also has to be put back for `su` to work.

Answer (score 12):

The correct permissions of `/bin/su` should be: **-rwsr-xr-x**

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 40128 May 17  2017 /bin/su*
```

In order to fix this specific issue you should:

1. Change file owner to be **root:root**
2. Change file permission to be **-rwsr-xr-x**

This can be done using:

```
sudo chown root:root /bin/su
sudo chmod 4755 /bin/su
```

- The first command, which change the owner of the file to be `root`.
- The next command will change the permission to allow read/execution by any user, and will set the `s` bit to the `/bin/su` command.

---

Q: Why performing `chown` on `/bin/su` also removed the `set-user-id` / `set-group-id` bits?

A: By design execution of `chown` might remove the `set-user-id` / `set-group-id` bits. When those bits are set, execution of such file, will result of running the file as the owner of the binary file, instead of the owner of the process which execute the file. Changing the file owner (or group) without removing the `set-user-id` bit, will result with a file which will be execute as different user then planned originally, which might result in a security hole.

**Some references:**

> [chown POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/chown.html)
>
> ```
> Unless chown is invoked by a process with appropriate privileges, the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits of a regular file shall be
> ```
>
> cleared upon successful completion; the set-user-ID and set-group-ID
>   bits of other file types may be cleared.

[Ubuntu `chown` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/chown.1.html) suggest running `info coreutils 'chown invocation'` in order to get the full documentation of `chown`

```
13.1 ‘chown’: Change file owner and group
=========================================

‘chown’ changes the user and/or group ownership of each given FILE to
NEW-OWNER or to the user and group of an existing reference file.
Synopsis:

....

   The ‘chown’ command sometimes clears the set-user-ID or set-group-ID
permission bits.  This behavior depends on the policy and functionality
of the underlying ‘chown’ system call, which may make system-dependent
file mode modifications outside the control of the ‘chown’ command.  For
example, the ‘chown’ command might not affect those bits when invoked by
a user with appropriate privileges, or when the bits signify some
function other than executable permission (e.g., mandatory locking).
When in doubt, check the underlying system behavior.
```

Comment: Or simply in one `chmod` command: `sudo chmod 4755 /bin/su`

Comment: @Videonauth - thanks for the comment! updated my answer.

Comment: I might explain the asymmetry that it takes a `chown` to get in OP's position, but a `chown` plus a `chmod` to get  back...

Comment: @EricTowers - thanks for your suggested to explain it. I've updated my answer and added an explanation to the behavior.

Comment: @jheel-rathod - if I've answer your question please [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) it